# Running arbitrary code at runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos

I know this is an odd question, but I'm wondering if this is possible. Is there any method by which code (which would be typed by a user) could be run *during runtime?*  For example, suppose I would allow the user to type in some Core Graphics drawing code.  I would want this code to be run in a `drawRect` method of my preview pane.

So what I would have to do would be to convert this group of strings into actual runtime code.

Is this even possible, or am I just wasting my time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few solutions:

1. Create a language of your own, and parse it in-application
2. If on mac, you could theoretically, create a function stub from what they enter in, and use GCC shipped with the application to compile the code at runtime into a dylib, and then use dylib functions to run the function you created.

Comment: Creating your own language for drawing is your best bet. If you actually allow them to run any C code they want, that's awfully dangerous. With your own language, you can dictate exactly what they can do, and if they're only performing a couple of drawing operations it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Well I'm not sure that would accomplish what I'm thinking about. If the goal is to let them create perfect drawing code (using Core Graphics functions) through live refreshing, then how would creating my own language help with that?  I'm not saying it's a bad idea; I just don't understand how it would help my situation.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, you can have your app send text to the compiler (several come with Xcode), have the code compiled, and run the compiled result as a slave app (controlled via a socket, for instance, and copying the preview pane image pixels back via a pipe).  If needed you could convert the source code text using some sort of preprocessor and wrap it in your own run-time shell.

Alternatively you could write or port a C language interpreter (there are several open source interpreters for various subsets of C), and plug Core Graphics library calls into the C interpreter's parser and run-time engine.

I do not know of a full interpreter for Objective C.